# json.log file with "Loki Logging Driver" Docker plugin

Tags: docker, logging, grafana-loki

I run a Docker container via Ansible playbook with, among the others, the following options in order to enable logging with Loki and then visualize them in Grafana

```
log_driver: loki
log_options: "loki-url=http://myaddress/loki/api/v1/push"

volumes:
   - "/var/log/docker/{{applicationName}}/:/var/log/{{applicationName}}/:rw"
```

All works (or seems to work) fine but at a certain point the container dimension grows progressively until the host disk space is saturated. If I restart the docker the problem seems to be resolved but it'll come back after a while.

Could the problem have to do with the file

```
/var/lib/docker/plugins/---id-plugin---/rootfs/var/log/docker/---container-id---/json.log
```

where *---id-plugin---* is the id of the `Loki Logging Driver` returned by `docker plugin ls` ?

Anyway, what is that file?

Thank you so much in advance.